# Is there a way to add a new column to a pandas dataframe, appending each unique value of the new column to every existing row of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe:

```
fruit_prices = [('apple', 5.99),
           ('orange', 4.99),
           ('pear', 6.99)]
labels = ['fruit', 'price']
fruit_prices = pd.DataFrame.from_records(datasets, columns=labels)

fruit_prices 
fruit    price    
apple    5.99     
orange   4.99     
apple    6.99
```

I would like to add a new column containing, for instance, only two values, but in a way that each of these unique values appears for each existing row in the original dataframe.

```
day = ['wednesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday']
```

The expected output:

```
fruit    price    day
apple    5.99     wednesday 
apple    5.99     thursday
orange   4.99     wednesday 
orange   4.99     thursday
apple    6.99     wednesday 
apple    6.99     thursday
```

I thought maybe I could use itertools after getting unique values from the new column/series only:

```
from itertools import cycle
dates = cycle(['wednesday','thursday'])
```

But I'm not sure how to assign this back to the dataframe (in a way that allows duplication of the existing rows) or if this is even a viable approach. I also thought about creating a single column dataframe from that Series and merging it, but this seems circuitous and I am also not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `cross join`:

```
day = ['wednesday', 'thursday']

df = fruit_prices.assign(A=1).merge(pd.DataFrame({'day':day,'A':1}), on='A', how='outer')
print (df)
    fruit  price  A        day
0   apple   5.99  1  wednesday
1   apple   5.99  1   thursday
2  orange   4.99  1  wednesday
3  orange   4.99  1   thursday
4    pear   6.99  1  wednesday
5    pear   6.99  1   thursday
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.cycle`:

```
day = ['wednesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday']
#list(set(day) 
#['wednesday', 'thursday']

from itertools import cycle, islice
df_new=pd.concat([df,df[::-1]],ignore_index=True)
df_new['day']=list(islice(cycle(list(set(day) )), len(df_new)))
print(df_new)

    fruit  price        day
0   apple   5.99  wednesday
1  orange   4.99   thursday
2   apple   6.99  wednesday
3   apple   6.99   thursday
4  orange   4.99  wednesday
5   apple   5.99   thursday
```